# How can I create Nested Lists in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: list

I have a simple two-level nested list that I'm trying to create - one for Projects and one for Users. The Project to User relationship is 1:n. I have a set of fields that are exclusive to projects, and a set of a fields that are exclusive to users. And both lists have their own workflows and actions defined.

What is the best way to create this in SharePoint 2013? I'm using SharePoint Designer and I don't see an intuitive way of creating a nested list as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no such thing as "nested lists" in SharePoint; but you can establish relationships between lists by creating lookup columns. So, if I understand your scenario correctly, you would have a multi-select lookup column in your Projects list called "Users" (or whatever you like) that would let you select the various users that are a part of this project.